# Is there any way to assign a custom permission to a content in ektron?

Tags: ektron

Am working in ektron 9.0. I  read about the custom permission from below article [Information about Custom Roles for your Developer](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v9.00/reference/Web/Users/Managing_Users_and_UserGroups.htm)

In that i found two methods **GetRolePermissionSystem** and **GetRolePermissionFolder**
mentioned.Is anyone know which ektron api these methods available.

Also i would like to know that, is there any way to associate a custom permission with a content or a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an older API and not a Framework API call. 
This is an example of using the API:

```
Ektron.Cms.CommonApi comApi = new Ektron.Cms.CommonApi();
  if (comApi.GetRolePermissionSystem("MyCustomRoleAdmin", comApi.UserId))
```

That example is for a system wide custom role that is not specific to a folder. While the  article you referenced seems to imply that GetRolePermissionFolder would work for a folder, I have never tried it.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question, there is no way to assign a custom permission to a folder.  Custom permissions can be set up in Ektron but they are designed for programmatic use only.  In other words "does the current user have custom permission X?"